# html email breaks in outlook web app

Tags: html, email, outlook

I am building a html email. it looks fine in outlook 2003, outlook 2007, hotmail, gmail, yahoo but in outlook web app has breaks between the rows. has anyone had these issues with outlook web app?

i have display block on the images but it looks like they get stripped out.

Comment: It's hard to tell without providing an example code or something like that!

Comment: Can you provde the html and css that you are using? I think I have previously experienced what you are going through. However i want to examine your mark up first before I come to a conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was fixed by wrapping the elements in `<span style="display:block"></span>`

E.G:

```
<a href="http://www.url.com">

  <img src="example.jpg" />

</a>
```

becomes

```
<a href="http://www.url.com">
 <span style="display:block;">
  <img src="example.jpg" />
 </span>
</a>
```

but needs doing on all broken elements

Comment: Yes, what do you mean? I'm having a similar issue where there is a break between table rows in OWA... but ONLY in Firefox and ONLY if the message is in another folder besides the Inbox. (I know right, freaking Microsoft.)

Answer (score 1):

Various styling is being stripped, so inline-styling will **NOT** work with images in OWA.

Here's a simple example of what Bill the Lizard was referring too:

**`<span style="display:block"><img src="myFancyImage.gif"/></span>`**

Without the above code it may look like extra padding/margin is creating space between tables and table rows/columns.... basically the issue that brought you to this page.

Answer (score 1):

Use this inline css

```
<span style="margin:0; padding:0; display:block;"><img src="myFancyImage.gif"/></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and unfortunately none of these solutions worked.

The *display:block* was always being striped out, no matter whether I wrapped the image in span or font tags.

Eventually, I found that wrapping the image in a DIV with inline width and height solved the problem. I guess because DIVs are block elements already, and it seems the only styles that OWA doesn't strip out are width and height.

e.g.

```
<td width="475" height="73" valign="top" bgcolor="#e9e9e9">
<div style="display:block;width:475px;height:73px"><img src="../images/email/email_02.jpg" alt="Three Barrels" width="475" height="73" style="display:block;border:none;outline:none;line-height:0;float:left;" /></div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the fix above and it didn't work - but this worked for me:

I just added this code at the top of the email code.

```
/* FIX FOR OWA */       
.bdyItmPrt img { display:block !important; }
```